# Method Produces --> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Whenever i put in this method

```
  private Stream createstream(this System.Drawing.Image image, ImageFormat format)
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, format);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

I keep getting

***Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class***

As far as  i know i'm not extending anything.Please advice

Comment: If you don't want to write an extension method, then remove the `this` from `this System.Drawing.Image image`

Comment: @canton7 done :) ....thanks.... do you mind adding it as an answer.

Comment: You could still make the method static, though, even if you don't want it as an extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler thinks you're trying to write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). Extension methods:

1. Are static methods
2. The first parameter has `this` at the start of it
3. Are defined in a non-generic static class

The compiler saw the `this` in your `this System.Drawing.Image image`, thought you were trying to write an extension method, and complained that you weren't meeting point 3.

If you don't intend to write an extension method, then remove the `this` from `this System.Drawing.Image image`.